# subdivison not working properly in render

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, subdivision-surface

[image: following a blender guru tutorial but the subdivision on the front side of the model is not displayed properly, please help me as i am starting new in this software]

following a blender guru tutorial but the subdivision on the front side of the model is not displayed properly, please help me as i am starting new in this software

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi, Nishchay Gawai .. welcome.. Can you describe the display you are expecting? Would that be a wire-frame overlay on the model?  (enabled in Properties editor, Object tab, Viewport Display)

Comment: as you can see in the image the front side of the anvil is not subdivided as in not smooth, you can see the sharp corners in the rendered image